# Show that $f(t-i) \star g(t-k)=m(t-i-k)$

Tags: convolution

Let $f,g\in L^1$, and let $m=f \star g$ the convolution product of $f$ and $g$, $i,k\in \mathbb Z.$ Show that $$f(t-i) \star g(t-k)=m(t-i-k)$$

---

\begin{align*}
f(t-i)\star g(t-i)&=f(t-i)\star g(t+i-i-k) \\&=f(t-i)\star h(t-i) \quad(h(t-i)=g(t-k)) \\
&=\int_{\mathbb R} f(t-i-s)h(s) \\&=\int_{\mathbb R} f(t-i-s)g(s+i-k)ds\\&=\int_{\mathbb R} f(t-i-k-s')g(s'+i)ds \quad (s'=s-k)\\
\end{align*}
I don't know how to complete the proof ! any help please ! I know it's a stupid question but I get stuck !

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by $f(t-i)\star g(t-k)$ ?
What is true is that
\begin{align*}
m(t-i-k)&=\int_{\mathbb R} f(t-i-k-s)g(s)ds \\
&=\int_{\mathbb R}f(t-i-u)g(u-k)du\\
&=(f\star \widetilde{g})(t-i),
\end{align*}
where $\widetilde{g}=g(\cdot-k)$.

Comment: Even me I have this question ! this is a course of my teacher which I don't understand ! What's $f(t)\star g(t)$ and what's its realtion to $(f\star g )(t)$ !